# Can't find cron job created by Chef custom recipe through OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I have the following code in a custom recipe which I run using the `execute_recipes` command in OpsWorks' deployment section:

```
cron "my_cron_job" do
  command "python /path/to/apythonfile.py"
end
```

When I access the instance through SSH and check /etc/crontab using root, I can't find this job there.
However, when looking at the Chef log for this command run, the relevant lines are there:

```
[Thu, 11 Apr 2013 21:24:23 +0000] DEBUG: Processing cron[my_cron_job] on instance1.localdomain
[Thu, 11 Apr 2013 21:24:23 +0000] DEBUG: Cron 'my_cron_job' not found
[Thu, 11 Apr 2013 21:24:23 +0000] INFO: Added cron 'my_cron_job'
```

So, where **CAN** I find the actual record of this cron job on the instance after this recipe is executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in `/etc/cron.d/my_cron_job`? I assume Chef uses the job name to create a separate file because it's easier to manage it instead of a crontab where other maybe non-chef jobs reside.

Comment: I searched there also, but there is only one file named `.placeholder` :(

Comment: Ah, the `cron` resource places your commands in user crontabs, esp. in the root crontab when no user is given.

Comment: For Debian 6 the user crontabs are placed in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` (source: `man crontab`)

Comment: Spot on! it was there :)  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using an instance with Amazon Linux, my cron jobs were listed under the root user. After ssh-ing into the instance, I ran

```
sudo -i       # Logs you in as root.
crontab -l    # Prints crontab
```

and they were printed to the terminal.